# Confused on how to combine results from two queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Query 1:

```
SELECT count(id) as conversions, SUM(user_payout) as amount, geoip.country_name, geoip.country_code
FROM conversions
LEFT JOIN geoip ON conversions.end_ip BETWEEN geoip.start_long AND geoip.end_long
WHERE user_id = 1
AND type != ''
AND status = 1
AND month(created_at) = month(now())
GROUP BY country_name
ORDER BY country_name ASC
```

Results:
[image: Query results]

Query 2:

```
SELECT count(id) as clicks, geoip.country_name, geoip.country_code
FROM clicks
LEFT JOIN geoip on clicks.ip BETWEEN geoip.start_long AND geoip.end_long
WHERE user_id = 1
AND month(created_at) = month(now())
GROUP BY country_name
ORDER BY country_name ASC
```

Results:
[image: Query results]

I'd like to combine the two so for each country, it shows clicks, conversions, country_name and country_code.

Can't figure out how to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine them using subqueries and `left outer join`:

```
select clicks.country_code, clicks.country_name,
       coalesce(clicks.clicks, 0) as clicks,
       coalesce(conversions.conversions, 0) as conversions
from (<subquery 2>) clicks left outer join
     (<subquery 1>) conversions
     on clicks.country_code = conversions.country_code;
```

This assumes that all countries have at least one click.

EDIT:

If the list of countries is in `geo_ip`, you can do:

```
select gi.country_code, gi.country_name, clicks.clicks, conversions.conversions
from (select distinct country_code, country_name
      from geo_ip
     ) gi left outer join
     (<subquery 2>) clicks
     on clicks.country_code = gi.country_code left outer join
     (<subquery 1>) conversions
     on conversions.country_code = gi.country_code;
```

Comment: I've tried that, bud, but it won't work if there are countries without clicks or countries without conversions. It just shows results where countries have both clicks and conversions.

Comment: @Prash . . . First, you should mention your real requirements in the question as well as any code that you have tried.  Second, where do you get the list of countries from, if they are not provided by the subqueries?

Comment: List of countries is from the GeoIP table @GordonLinoff

Comment: Countries are retrieved from the LEFT JOIN on the geoip tables

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be working just fine :) Just trying to filter out where clicks and conversions are null

Comment: @Prash . . . Use the `coalesce()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Left Join clicks on the first query to geoip.

Or you could use a union but you would have go get each result to only show clicks, conversions, country_name and country_code by only selecting those in the select statement.

Comment: Could you please expand on your first statement? :)